# Exception when using <c:forEach> tag in jsp file

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I am using tiles+spring mvc. In my jsp when I try to use  tag, it is giving be the exception which is present in the below trace. I tried with/without the below dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>${jstl-jstl}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>${taglibs-standard}</version>
</dependency>
```

My web.xml has the below header

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

Exception Trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp'.
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:61) ~[tiles-request-servlet-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]

Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:846) ~[jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:na]

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.unExposeVariables(LoopTagSupport.java:620) ~[javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar:na]
```

Comment: are you sure, if you remove the core tag imports OR comment the foreach code from the jsp, it is rendering ??..... It seems to me like some issue with view resolver configuration in Spring context xml file.

Comment: If I comment forEach code, the view is getting rendered properly without any issue.

Comment: Then check out whether you have added `jstl` jar

Comment: Yes. I have added jstl-1.2 jar and is mentioned in my query too :)